# AEM Sightly - How to loop through component child nodes

Tags: aem, sightly

I have a 'container' component for housing child components. Essentially, a container for holding tabs of content, where the user can drag in as many 'tabs'  as they choose.

The code is as such:

```
<!--/* Tab Container Component */-->
<div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}"><h2>Drag a 'Tab Panel' below:</h2></div>
<ul data-sly-list.tab="${list of children in the tab-container parsys}">
    <li>${tab.tabName}</li> //these will be the tabs using jQuery-UI
</ul>
<div data-sly-resource="${ @path='tab-container',resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}" data-sly-unwrap></div>
```

And the 'tab' component:

```
<!--/* Tab Panel Component */-->
<div class="tab-panel">
<div data-sly-resource="${ @path='tab-   panel',resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}" data-sly-unwrap></div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to use the container component to loop through the items in its parsys and pull out the property 'tabName' of each item. The node structure ends up as shown:[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AEM Sightly to get properties of child nodes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005505/aem-sightly-to-get-properties-of-child-nodes)

Comment: So, in trying to use the WCMUse, I seem to be getting an error "com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUse Failed to activate Use class"

Comment: Does it tell you where the error in activation is? I had something similar around NPE when the Use class was being activated on install & didn't have access to a `currentPage` object — managed to resolve with some defensive checks

Answer (score 0):

This might work in your case:

```
<ul data-sly-list.tab="${resource.listChildren}">
    <li>${tab.name}</li> //these will be the tabs using jQuery-UI
</ul>
```

Basically, the `tab-container` is your parsys and `resource.listChildren` will list all the `child resources/nodes`.  `tab.name` is provided by `HTL` which will give you `tab_panel, tab_panel_1134.., etc.`.  Other properties inside of each `tab-panel (tab)` too can be accessed.

Another way to get directly to a resource is with `data-sly-use`:

- with this you can reach any resource in AEM. [Docs here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/block-statements.html) (look for `data-sly-use with resources`).

Good Luck...